# order by in sql join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an sql query which returns exactly the data I require.  However, I'm having trouble with the Order By.  I think I may need some sort of nested select or a Group By but I have never done one of those, so I wondered if someone could assist. The data needs to be sorted firstly by centre_id, then by learner_name and then by journey_centre_start but it only seems to sort by centre_id and learner_name and ignores the sort for journey_centre_start.

Journey_centre_start is a date type with a NULL default value in the database.

```
SELECT a.learner_id
     , a.learner_name
     , a.centre_id
     , a.learner_status
     , b.journey_id
     , c.journey_centre_start
  FROM learner a
  JOIN learner_journey b  
    ON a.learner_id = b.learner_id
  JOIN journey c 
    ON b.journey_id = c.journey_id
 WHERE a.centre_id != 999
   AND a.learner_status = 'complete'
 ORDER 
    BY a.centre_id ASC 
     , a.learner_name ASC 
     , c.journey_centre_start ASC;
```

Comment: What type is `journey_centre_start`? _If it is a text field holding a date value, that probably explains your problem; it would be sorting it alphabetically._

Comment: Also, if journey_centre_start is a nullable column, the query will return ordered by centre_id, learner_name and null  before sorting by journey_centre_start.

Comment: I've checked and journey_centre_start is a date type with NULL as default.    Can it still be sorted?  Thanks

Comment: You can sort by date. It doesn't appear that you should need to nest anything and grouping doesn't have anything to do with the problem as you've described it. The best idea now is for us to see a sample of the data that you think is sorted incorrectly.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action:1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the NULL values in journey_centre_start to be at the bottom of the list then you can add a CASE statement to your ordering`

```
  SELECT a.learner_id
 , a.learner_name
 , a.centre_id
 , a.learner_status
 , b.journey_id
 , c.journey_centre_start
  FROM learner a
 JOIN learner_journey b  
  ON a.learner_id = b.learner_id
 JOIN journey c 
  ON b.journey_id = c.journey_id
 WHERE a.centre_id != 999
 AND a.learner_status = 'complete'
 ORDER 
 BY a.centre_id ASC 
 , a.learner_name ASC 
 , CASE WHEN c.journey_centre_start IS NULL THEN 2 ELSE 1 END
 , c.journey_centre_start ASC
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but still no joy.  As all the learners are complete they will always have a journey_centre_start date so there are no null values returned in this column in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone who responded to my post.  By talking it through it actually dawned on me that the solution was quite simple.  I just needed to change round the Order By statement to:
ORDER BY a.centre_id ASC, c.journey_centre_start ASC, a.learner_name ASC and it gave me the result I wanted.
Kindest regards to you all.